# Set and Retrieve Array in Joomla Session Namespace

Tags: joomla-3.x, jsession, namespace

I have the need to use a namespace in session, so I am using the following to set the session:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$customOrder['items'][] = $itemArray;
$session->set("order", $customOrder, 'my_custom_namespace');
```

This works great. If I then print the entire `$session`, I can see the `my_custom_namespace` and the expected values, like so:

```
[__my_custom_namespace] => stdClass Object ( [order] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [6] => 1 ) )
```

So far, so good! However, I am struggling to retrieve the data. I expected this to work, but it does not:

```
$session    = JFactory::getSession();
$orderData  = $session->get('order', 'items', 'my_custom_namespace');
```

Instead, this just prints out `items`. It doesn't seem to matter what I try to use in place of `order` or `items`, it just prints the second parameter from the `get()` when I `print_r($orderData)`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The fact that `get()` is returning the string `item` means that order isn't in the session (or more likely the session isn't there/accessible). [Highlighted Docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Session.Session.html#method_getId#:~:text=mixed%20$default%20=%20null) We will need to investigate why your session data is not accessible.  Please take out [tour] and continue to investigate your issue.  If you can offer more details, please edit your question. If you manage to resolve this before someone else helps, please post an answer to your question.

Comment: Question closed as "Off-topic: Could not be Replicated" because issue was a case-sensitive error that was not presented in the question details.

Answer (score 1):

The above method is 100% correct and working. My own code, where I had `my_custom_namespace` had a typo - I was setting `myNamespace` and trying - and obviously failing - to get `MyNamespace` :Faceplam: